# Bom não consigo capturar o texto quando clico na opção 3 so me retorna o value 3. Ajuda

Tags: php, javascript

```
    echo "              <td><label for=\"opcao1\"></label></td>";
    echo "              <td><input name=\"origem\" value=\"Azul\" id=\"Azul\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==false){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=true;}\">Azul</td>";
    echo "          </tr>";
    echo "          <tr>";
    echo "              <td><label for=\"opcao2\">Origem</label></td>";
    echo "              <td><input name=\"origem\" value=\"Vermelho\" id=\"Vermelho\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==false){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=true;}\">Vermelho</td>";
    echo "          </tr>";
    echo "          <tr>";
    echo "              <td><label for=\"opcao3\"></label></td>";
    echo "              <td><input name=\"origem\" value=\"outros\" id=\"outros\" type=\"radio\" onclick=\"if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==true){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=false;}\">";
    echo "               Outros<input name=\"textOutrosOrigem\"  size=\"20\" id=\"textOutrosOrigem\" type=\"text\" style=\"width: 100%;\" \"height: 120px;\" disabled=\"disabled\"></br></br></td>";
    echo "          </tr>";
```

---

Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    

     window.onload = function () {

        document.getElementById('outros').onchange = habilitarCampo;
        }
        function habilitarCampo(){
        alert('dffwdfd');
            if document.getElementById('outros').checked == false;
            {
                document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled = true;
                document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').text = '';
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled = false;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Se puder colocar seu código em um editor online para melhor entendimento, como por exemplo http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: Posta seu código http://www.codepen.io para que possamos entender melhor o que você está fazendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago,

Segue o código

```js
function teste() {
  if (document.getElementById('Azul').checked == true) {
    console.log('Azul');
  } else if (document.getElementById('Vermelho').checked == true) {
    console.log('Vermelho');
  } else {
    if (document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').value != "") {
      console.log(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').value);
    } else {
      alert('Origem invalida!');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<td><label for="opcao1"></label></td>
    <td><input name="origem" value="Azul" id="Azul" type="radio" onclick="if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==false){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=true;}">Azul</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="opcao2">Origem</label></td>
    <td><input name="origem" value="Vermelho" id="Vermelho" type="radio" onclick="if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==false){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=true;}">Vermelho</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label for="opcao3"></label></td>
    <td><input name="origem" value="outros" id="outros" type="radio" onclick="if(document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled==true){document.getElementById('textOutrosOrigem').disabled=false;}">
     Outros<input name="textOutrosOrigem"  size="20" id="textOutrosOrigem" type="text" style="width: 100%;" "height: 120px;" disabled="disabled"></br></br></td>
</tr> 
</table>
<button onclick="teste()">TESTE</button>
```

Comment: Opaa Valew deu certo aqui. Obrigado mesmo